# How to write Python 3 code in a Java web code?

Tags: java, python, web-services, jsp, jython

I am trying to write inside a JSP/Servlet Java web project, a python-3 Machine Learning code depends on torch and some advanced frameworks.

I tried:

1. to use **Jython** but it did not work because it only works for
   python 2 programs.
2. to use **ProcessBuilder**  and
   **Runtime.getRuntime().exec("pythonFile.py")** to execute the python file but nothing
   worked.

Is there any suggestions on how to write that Python code in the Java project or communicate them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For option #2, you'd need to pass the python executable into the exec method.  For example:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python pythonFile.py")
```

Source: https://www.edureka.co/community/358/how-to-execute-a-python-file-with-few-arguments-in-java